# Currency block?

Tags: commerce

I need to be able to accept donations in different currencies. In Commerce 2 I see that currencies are tied to stores. Is there currently any solution that allows users to choose their currency from a block or similar?

Answer (score 0):

The module [Commerce currency switcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_currency_switcher) does that. Unfortunately there is no country detection for now, by it may be handled with Rules.